# Absolute continuous function and Jensen inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an absolute continuous function, such as $f' \in L^4(0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$. Find $r<0$, such as, for all $\alpha \geq r,$ $lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} x^{\alpha}f(x)=0.$

Things I know:
1) $f$ is absolute continuous, so  $f'$ exists, $f'\in L^1(0,1)$ and 
$f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x} f'(x) dx=\int_{0}^{x} f'(x) dx$  for all $x \in [0,1]$.

2) Using Jensen inequality we have $|f(x)|^4\leq (\int_{0}^{x} |f'(x)| dx)^4 \leq \int_{0}^{x} |f'(x)|^4 dx\leq \int_{0}^{1} |f'(x)|^4 dx$.
So $|f(x)|\leq ||f'||_{4}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

3) $x^{\alpha}|f(x)|\leq x^{\alpha} ||f'||_{4}$

Now I'm stuck, I think I should use that $\int_{0}^{1} 1/x^{\alpha} dx<\infty$ if $\alpha>1$ but I don't know what to do.
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: For Jensen's inequality, you need a measure with total mass $1$, so you should not raise $\int_0^x \lvert f'(t)\rvert\,dt$ to the fourth power, but something close to that that gives you a total measure of $1$ for $[0,x]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I understand how to solve the problem!